# What is Tornado's counterpart of Web.py's ctx module?

Tags: python, web-services, tornado, web.py

I would like to learn how to use something like web.py's ctx module in tornado.

Thanks!

---

Edit:
I am trying to save user's credentials in a global context like with the ctx module. I know that such information can be passed with each request, but in that case I will need to pass this information to handlers each time? I wonder what is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of the information contained in `ctx` from the [`RequestHandler.request`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.request) object, which is a [`tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest) instance.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
         # This is just some of the attributes available.
         print("host is {0.host}, ip is {0.ip}, HTTP method"
               " is {0.method}, protocol is {0.protocol}".format(self.request))
```

A few of the things that are contained in `ctx` you may have to pull out of `self.request.headers`, but I think it's all there.

Tornado doesn't provide anything equivalent to the session data `ctx` provides. Tornado is designed to be stateless, so this is purposely not implemented.

Note that tornado does provide some useful methods for dealing with authentication. One is a decorator called [`tornado.web.authenticated`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.authenticated), which you can use to decorate any method you want the user to be authenticated to access. You should also implement `get_current_user`, which is what the `authenticated` decorator uses to determine if the user is authenticated, and [`get_login_url`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_login_url), which should return the url the user should be redirected to if they're not logged in (usually this should be your login page). When a user logs in, you can use [`set_secure_cookie`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_secure_cookie) to store their session in a secure cookie, and then call [`get_secure_cookie`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_secure_cookie) inside `get_current_user` to validate the session later.

See this question for more general information on handling sessions with Tornado: [standard way to handle user session in tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15254538/2073595)

Comment: Thanks! I meant to save user's credentials in the global environment, so in this case I need to pass credentials with each individual function calls? I wonder what's the correct way for doing that?