# Correct work with template

Tags: python, tornado

Sorry. I do not speak English.

I want to make a page that have one form. In this form I have a input box that users can enter usernames and i check if user exists or not. If user doesn't exist, show an error , otherwise go to another page.

Question 1. Is this right to do?

index.html

```
{% if data_page['validator_name'] %}
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <label>{{ data_page['validator_name'] }}</label>
{% else %}
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
{% end %}
</div>
```

demo.py

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
            self.render("index.html",data_page={'validator_name':False})

    def post(self):

        user_name = self.get_argument("name")

        if self.validate_user_name(user_name):
            self.redirect("/chat")
        else:
            self.render("index.html",data_page={'validator_name':"Name already use",'post_name':user_name})
```

Question 2. Go back.

If the user is unique, page redirect to "/chat". If users click on browser "back" button, That form will be showed that we passed. Will introduce the user under which we stopped. And if there was an error message, it will be. How to do that would pre return, the form was the original?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the username and it's be correct, you should set secure_cookie or session for this user.

In each request, you should check for the session(or cookie) value to determine if user logged in or not. with this way, if user click on back button, you check the status of user and decide to redirect or show login form again.

(in other way, you can use flash messages and notification system which is be in session systems. these kind of messages sets, and shown once. in other word, you can set a flash message for incorrect username message. this will appear once when call flash message.)

check these pages :

[standard way to handle user session in tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254538/standard-way-to-handle-user-session-in-tornado)

https://gist.github.com/ayang/1735032

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycket/0.1